# what is use of scipy.misc library in machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am training a Generative adversarial network. I referred many examples and they have scipy.misc in common. I came across [this website](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/misc.html) but it didn't help.

What is use of this particular library.

Comment: Your question is too broad and not specific at all, its not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks @Maitas . But, I received correct explanation for my question and that is all I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Website you stated:

> Miscellaneous routines (scipy.misc)
>
> Various utilities that don’t have
>   another home.

So the use is to have a place to put routines, which do not necessarily fit somewhere else. Imagine it as a drawer where one puts all the things that one does not know where to put them, but one does not want to have them laying around in order to find them easier.

For more detail you might want to take a closer look into the routines (into your drawer), in order to explore which functionalities are covered by `scipy.misc`

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand what scipy.misc is meant for :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @vanilla.I will vote when I get more than 15 reputations. I want to vote. But, am not allowed to:-(